# Account Contact Relationship : Can we select Indirect Contacts in Account Contact Relation for case

Tags: accountcontactrelation

Consider a given scenario where

1. Case is assigned to an account ABC
2. ABC is parent which has child as A,B, C
3. Account Contact relationship object has below 4 records

   - Contact Tom Account ABC
   - Contact Kim Account A
   - Contact Jerry Account B
   - Contact Meny Account C
4. Now we want the user to select any one contact to the case from the account contact relationship.
5. We have an lookup of contact on case object.

Currently we are able to show & select the contacts which are directly linked to the account.
Like in our above example we are able to select ABC & not A, B or C

Basically what we want to know if it is possible to select Indirect Contacts in Account Contact Relation for case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to select Indirect Contacts in Account Contact Relation for Case..

Suppose In creating a Case,

Select **Tom** from the Contact lookup and then Account Lookup will take the Account name of its related Account, in this case: **ABC**

If you want to change the Account name from ABC to any other -

select the Account lookup and in that you will see a search box at the top, clear/remove the auto-populated value in search box and select Go and you can select any Account from the generated account list and save your case.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs...Not sure how the account lookup will be prepopulated.

Comment: sorry @VishalNayak to use the word pre-populated but I meant to say that while creating a case, as soon as you select a contact from the lookup, its related account name gets filled in the Account field.

I have edited my answer, still you have any question then let me know.